# How can I programmatically retrieve a list of project file names from Project Server?

Tags: ms-project, project-server, ms-project-server-2013, ms-project-server-2010, ms-project-server-2016

I have a tool that needs to open Project files to get data out of them. Some of these project files are hosted on the Project Server site rather than a network location that can be browsed to with a normal file explorer.

I know you can open files that are hosted on Project Server using the [FileOpenEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fileopenex) method using the `<>\[FileName]` notation. I just need to get a list of the project names on Project server.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?